# using unicode_literals with __slots__ on python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pylint, python-unicode

I'm trying to convert my Python 2.7 program to use `from __future__ import unicode_literals` but have pylint yelling at me that I can't put unicode strings as `__slots__` members.

Do you know if it really poses a problem, or unicode/string are the same for `__slots__` implementation? from Python's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots) it seems that any immutable object is OK, but I'm not sure.

Example code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

class Foo(object):
    __slots__ = ('a', 'b')
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

foo = Foo(5,7)
print foo.a
print foo.b
```

Pylint gives this error message:

```
a.py|4 col 18 error| [invalid-slots-object] Invalid object "u'a'" in __slots__, must contain only non empty strings [python/pylint]
```

But it seems to work fine.

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message, which when used in a websearch doesn't turn up anything useful? Also, how about some code? Then, I believe that the unicode literals future also provides the 'b' prefix to explicitly specify a byte-string, in case that matters.

Comment: It indeed provided the b'' str notation to create literal string objects, and it indeed solves the problem. Thanks! (I will edit the question to be more meaningful for future searches)

Comment: Actually, making this question better for searching is a positive thing, but what I wanted to suggest is that you just throw the error message itself and "pylint" at a websearch and check if your question wasn't answered before.

Comment: already did. no luck :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *This is a self-answer, originally pasted into the question body by the questioner.*

When importing `unicode_literals`, you can use the `b''` notation to declare non-unicode strings, and they are exactly what `__slots__` need.

Comment: This seems to be a perfect case for a community wiki answer. :)